# How to print Select with python and postgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm doing a program where the user can see all the order they made. Using the following code to print all the information:

```
@classmethod
    def load_view_order_by_email(cls, email):
        with CursorFromConnectionPool() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SELECT product_1, product_2, product_3, product_4, product_5, order_date FROM customer_order WHERE customer_email=%s ', (email,))
            user_data = cursor.fetchone()
            for x in cursor:
                print("View all order")
                print(x)
```

just do not print all the information, it seems that for starts index 1 instead of 0.
In the debug, it says that there are 3 lines with information directing to the user X.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "missing" data is in your `user_data` variable.

This statement pulls the first row from the result set

```
user_data = cursor.fetchone()
```

This block iterates over the *remaining* rows in the result set (1,2)

```
for x in cursor:
    print(x)
```